# Comparing the value from a multidimensional array with the index of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following two arrays:

```
$cars = array("BMW", "VW", "Kia", "Ford", "Ferrari", "Lamborghini"); 

$for_sale = array(
  array(
   "engine_capacity" => "1600",
   "car_id" => 5,
   "year" => 1937),
  array(
   "engine_capacity" => "2400",
   "car_id" => 0,
   "year" => 1937),
  array(
   "engine_capacity" => "2000",
   "car_id" => 3,
   "year" => 1937),
  array(
   "engine_capacity" => "2000",
   "car_id" => 4,
   "year" => 1937),
  array(
   "engine_capacity" => "4800",
   "car_id" => 2,
   "year" => 1937),
  array(
   "engine_capacity" => "6000",
   "car_id" => 1,
   "year" => 1937),
);
```

I am trying to match the index from $cars to the 'car_id' value from $for_sale and then display the matching car name. ie "car_id" => 0 will display BMW and so forth. I've looked at various similar questions but they are of very little help.Any help would be greatley appreciated as I've been failing miserably at this task. Thankx.

Comment: So, ok, and your current code is .. ?

Comment: My current code is not working at all that's why I did not add it.But I have been trying to use a foreach loop to loop over the array and compare teh values.

Comment: Even if it's not working, you should add it. Even if it's pseudo-code. Then it will be obvious that you've done some efforts, and, besides, it will be possible to find mistakes in your code (or may be it's going in wrong direction). It's StackOverflow and here we expect your code in the first time

Comment: Ok I'll post the code I currently have now..

Comment: `while(list($carkey, $carvalue) = each ($cars)){
    if($carkey == $tempcar){
      echo $carvalue."<br>"; 
    }
    $tempcar++;
  }
     //testing to match car_id to car key.
   foreach($for_sale as $sale){
    foreach($sale as $key => $value){     
       if($key  == car_id){
         $temp = 2;
         if($value == $temp){
          echo $carvalue;
          $temp++;  
         } 
       }    
     $temp++;
    }
   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine the two arrays, in order to have `car_id` and `car_name` inside `$for_sale` array, try with this :

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($cars) && $i < count($for_sale); $i++) {
    $for_sale[$i]['car_name'] = $cars[$i];
}

var_dump($for_sale);
```

**[PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dbh-pdh)**

Comment: Thank you so much, I've only being doing php for one semester and this was boggling my mind.. I understand how it's done now.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($cars) && $i < count($for_sale); $i++) {
        $for_sale[$i]['car_id'] = $cars[$i];
    }

    var_dump($for_sale);
```

change `$for_sale[$i]['car_name']` into `$for_sale[$i]['car_id']` you will get correct result
now [0] will be index of BMW and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to output the value of cars based on car_id, where car_id is the index of cars, like:

```
echo $cars[$for_sale[1]['car_id']]
```

this should echo `BMW`

**Edit:**

to display all car names that are for sale, this would be an approach:

```
foreach($for_sale as $fs) {
    if (isset($cars[$fs['car_id']])) {
        echo $cars[$fs['car_id']];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankx for your input, almost what I wanted to achieve,I appreciate all the help I can get so thank you once again. I have it working now.

Comment: youre welcome :) .. i misuderstood your question, but you could also achieve adding the car name to the forsale array with this approach.. if you liked my answer you may upvote it though :)

Comment: I would love to upvote it but I've just joined today I need to build up a rep, but as soon as I can i will!

Answer (score -1):

**    Use this code its working..**

```
foreach($for_sale as $k =>$v){
  foreach($cars as $key => $val){
     if($for_sale[$k]['car_id'] == $key){
       echo $cars[$key]; 
     }
  }       
}
```

Another way of solving this problem is :

```
foreach($for_sale as $k =>$v){
  $for_sale[$k]['car_name'] = $cars[$v['car_id']];
}
```

Comment: @mansoulx  : My frnd your answer is not matching the requirment.Please debugg your code.

Comment: dude why did somebody put down my answer, you can check my code its working dumbo.